# IP Traceroute RFC 1393

Tags: ipv4, icmp, traceroute, rfc

Is [RFC 1393](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1393) implemented by real routers in practice?

Are there any tools that generate traceroutes using it?

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out, that RFC 791 defines a record route option, which you will find deployed more widely. I think neither is used often, so it may be easy to confuse the two.

Comment: Thanks, I am using record route already and it appears to be well supported on the Internet. One limitation of record route is that it can only store the first 9 hops (more won't fit in the IPv4 header)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new ICMP message type as defined in this RFC actually was added to the ICMP standard - though it's currently listed as Historic in [RFC 6918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6918#section-2.6):

```
 2.6. Traceroute (Type 30)
   This message type is specified in [RFC1393] and was meant to provide
   an alternative means to discover the path to a destination system.
   This message type has never been widely deployed.  The status of
   [RFC1393] has been changed to Historic by [RFC6814], and the
   corresponding option this message type relies on (Traceroute, Type
   82) has been formally obsoleted by [RFC6814].
```

And mentioned in [RFC 6814](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6814#section-2.3) where it's formally deprecated:

```
   The Traceroute option is defined in [RFC1393].  The Traceroute option
   is defined as Experimental; it was never widely deployed on the
   public Internet.
```

I very much doubt there would be any current tools that would support this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [RFC6814](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6814#section-2.3) which obsoletes RFC1393

> ###2.3. Traceroute
>
> The Traceroute option is defined in [RFC1393].  The Traceroute option
> is defined as Experimental; it was never widely deployed on the
> public Internet.

So yes there should have been implementations for this (some one even implemented IP over avian carriers) but I've never seen one.